# Filtering LDAP returned attributes

Tags: ldap, openldap, ldap-query

So we have this LDAP query (against OpenLdap)

```
(&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(member=cn=admin,dc=test,dc=com))
```

The query returns all groups that **admin** is member of. It also returns all other users in those groups. This is an issue when you have +10.000 users that are in the same group.

Is there a way to just return the group names? Like an returned attributes filter?

In Java there is an option like that but I don't know if it just does the query and filters the results clientside, or how to write it as a LDAP query. Example:

```
String returnedAtts[]={"memberOf","name","mail"};
search.setReturningAttributes(returnedAtts);
NamingEnumeration answer = ctx.search(searchBase, "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName="+username+"))", search);
```

Yes I know. Using **memberOf** would be a more better option. But this LDAP doesn't have that attribute

Comment: You have an LDAP search filter injection when building filter with simple string concatenation, e.g. if someone provides username="*)(otherattr=specialvalue"

Comment: A filter like (&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(member=cn=admin,dc=test,dc=com))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `setReturningAttributes(list)`, LDAP server will return only those. You do not have to include the attributes your search filter is based on. This is the correct solution to your problem.

Comment: what is the ldap-query behind that method?

Comment: There is no ldap-query behind "setReturningAttributes" method - it only configures search-context to request necessary attributes when search is performed via the "search" method.

Answer (score 1):

A filter like
`(&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(member=cn=admin,dc=test,dc=com))`
should not return all the member(s) of the groups. It will return all the groups that the user is a member of.

A filter like
`(&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(cn=yourdesiredgroupname)(member=cn=admin,dc=test,dc=com))`

Will return only the group of interest. Setting the returned attributes to CN will return only the group name.

Comment: It returns alle the groups of that user yes, but since each member is an attribute on those groups we get back all the users as well.